# How to select this in imarcos

Tags: imacros

How I extract from this string:

```
href="/browse/likes?id=10151978212182045"
```

using imacros and then put it in a CSV file

The problem is that the ID Tag changes every time I visit the site. Below is an excerpt from the page.

```
<div class="UFILikeSentenceText" data-reactid=".h.1:0.0.$right.0.$left.0">
    <span data-reactid=".h.1:0.0.$right.0.$left.0.0">
       <a id="js_2" aria-label="Kate KoKo
            Socola Dang
            M AttiKa Ka
            Jane Jenielle
            Nong Ja
            Tungaoe Little
            Minmin Qiv
            Kui Saejia
            Ma Vie Ma Meilleure
            หญิง ต่าย
            สกุลนา ชนมาไกล
            Noonnin Waree
            Cher CH
            เจ้าหญิง น้ำแข็ง
            PanDii Kitty Roengsak
            กุ๊ฟกิ๊ฟ บ้าบอ
            Rabbit'fyz Rasberr-y
            Egg E Eight'egg
            T Napat Jiara W
            and 912 more..." rel="dialog" ajaxify="/ajax/browser/dialog/likes?id=10151978212182045" href="/browse/likes?id=10151978212182045" data-hover="tooltip" data-tooltip-alignh="center" role="button" data-reactid=".h.1:0.0.$right.0.$left.0.0.$range0:0">931 people</a>
    <span data-reactid=".h.1:0.0.$right.0.$left.0.0.$end:0:$0:0"> like this.</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:UFILikeSentenceText EXTRACT=TXT
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Hi buddy you can try this i think it will work.

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:UFILikeSentenceText EXTRACT=HTM
Set !VAR1 Eval("var exp = '{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/ href=.(.*?)\"/); exp[1];")
SET !EXTRACT "href="{{!VAR1}}""
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\ FILE=Link.csv
```

Comment: "var exp = '{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/ href=.(.*?)\"/); exp[1];"
Is this Imacro language ?
can you please guide me to understand this